# Change a normal submit 'input' type to 'button' type with button tag

Tags: theming, 8, forms

Is it possible in Drupal 8 to change a regular form submit button from Drupal into a button tag?

This is the output I need to achieve:

```
<button type="button" class="search-box__button">
  <svg class="icon search-box__open">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/build/img/svg-sprite.svg#icon-search"></use>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well that was quick... I used my intuition and was able to accomplish it by doing the following:

#### In mytheme.theme:

```
/**
 * @param $suggestions
 * @param array $variables
 */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_input_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  if (isset($element['#attributes']['data-twig-suggestion'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'input__' . $element['#type'] . '__' . $element['#attributes']['data-twig-suggestion'];
  }
}

/**
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-results') {  
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['data-twig-suggestion'] = 'search_results_submit';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-box__button';
  }
}
```

#### In input--submit--search-results-submit.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for an 'input' #type form element.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: A list of HTML attributes for the input element.
 * - children: Optional additional rendered elements.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_input()
 */
#}
<button{{ attributes }}>
  <svg class="icon search-box__open">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/themes/custom/mytheme/build/img/svg-sprite.svg#icon-search"></use>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Form still submits and functions as expected. Is this the general approach or at least acceptable? I will go with this unless there is a better way.

Comment: Looks good. Don't think there is a twig only solution, so you need to do something like this. Theme suggestion like you did or one big input.html.twig with all input versions which you select by the attributes you set in form alter.

Comment: I'll probably want to use a data-attribute on the tag instead of just the name, most likely.

Comment: Yep - I changed it to a data attribute so it doesn't interfere with anything else that may be relying on the name attribute. Works great.

Comment: To use for all use:
`<button{{ attributes }}>{{ attributes.value }}</button>`

Comment: Following up on comment from @VSS , to convert all input type="submit" to buttons, add `input--submit.htm.twig` to your theme with contents: `<button{{ attributes|without('value') }}>{{ attributes.value }}</button>`.

Answer (score 6):

You simply could use [`inline_template`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!InlineTemplate.php/class/InlineTemplate/8.2.x).

```
$build['hello']  = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => '<button type="button" class="search-box__button">
     <svg class="icon search-box__open">
       <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/build/img/svg-sprite.svg#icon-search"></use>
     </svg>
   </button>',
];
```

Comment: Won't you lose anything added on by `{{ attributes }}`?

Comment: I guess you would have to set your own attributes in the `'#context'` array.