# Button with different value and label / text

Tags: 8, forms

in Drupal 8, I want my form display such a (submit) button:

```
<button name="name" type="submit" value="value">Not the value</button>
```

So basically, the button value (that will be submitted) shall be different than the button text / label (following that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171664/html-submit-button-different-value-button-text)).

Is that possible with the Form API? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a duplicate of a question I posted a few weeks ago for Drupal 8.

Original question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/226494/57

Some more write up: http://kevinquillen.com/drupal/2017/01/28/adding-twig-template-suggestions-for-form-elements

Basically I wanted to target just one submit, hence that technique. Simply changing the `#type` to `button` is not enough in the Form API to get that result you're asking for.

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder if I can avoid defining a new twig template. Because interestingly, my Drupal already generates a `<button>...</button>`. And I could not find out which Twig template it is using. It's obviously not `input.html.twig`. Do you have an idea where `<button>` comes from?

Comment: ... My form is simply defined with `$form['go'] = ['#type' => 'submit', ...]`

Comment: Ah sorry, I guess I figured it out. I'm using Bootstrap and there is a `input--button.html.twig`. :)

Comment: I figured - I am not using Bootstrap. Drupal core does not provide an input button twig suggestion, themes have to. But otherwise, know that if you overwrite `input--button.html.twig` it will affect *all* button submits, which is why I am isolating and creating new suggestions for them. Particularly in my case, where there could be different SVG icons or something totally different depending on the form.

Comment: Sure, I didn't have in mind to change the template. But knowing now which is used I can hook into the preprocess. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could solve it myself. Since I'm using [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap), I could hook into its button template `input__button`:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_input__button(&$variables) {

  if (!empty($variables['element']['#label'])) {
    $variables['label'] = $variables['element']['#label'];
  }
}
```

With that, I can now define a label using the Form API:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#name' => 'some_name',
  '#value' => 'some_value_to_send',
  '#label' => $this->t('Label to show'),
  '#button_type' => 'primary',
];
```

(If Bootstrap [applies my patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2851655) then the hook will get obsolete.)