# Use form id as part of a form input twig file name

Tags: 8, theming

### Problem

I would like to have a theme suggestion for form elements (e.g. input, select, etc) that includes the form's ID. This would be nice for when I only want to make changes to the elements of that form and no other forms.

Currently I can use `input.twig.html` or `input--textfield.twig.html` for overriding a textfield. Therein lies the problem, neither of these theme suggestions are specific enough to only target the textfield for a specific form. I'm looking for the ability to have `input--textfield--[FORM_ID].html.twig` file.

Futhermore, it would be ideal to have a theme suggestion as follows `input--[FIELD_NAME]--[FORM_ID].html.twig` as this would allow a per field per form override.

### Research

I have been unsuccessful in my research for finding a solution to this problem. Also, I am confused why this is not already in the theme suggestions (this is most likely to do my lack of knowledge on the twig system).

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and this may not be the _ideal_ approach you are looking for, but I solved this another way http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226491/change-a-normal-submit-input-type-to-button-type-with-button-tag

Comment: Yes, I did read your blog post about it and like you said it may not be *ideal*. If this isn't something that Drupal is providing by a default, then I'm at a loss as to why. It seems very limiting and that is something that Drupal usually doesn't do.

Comment: Like you said, there is a generic way to add more suggestions, but they wind up touching _every_ element when in most cases you just want to touch one or two and leave the rest alone.

Comment: I'm not sure how bad this idea would be but what about implementing hook_form_alter() to hit every form. Then loop over every element to create a twig file suggestion like you did but this would hit every form. I'm not sure what the impact would be.

Comment: One way to do it, sure.

Comment: I will leverage what you've done and add in the form_id for every element for every form. Then I'll post it back to see if it is a viable solution. More worried about performance at that point. Not sure what the impact will be if anything at all.

Comment: If you can get the form ID from $variables using [template_preprocess_input](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/template_preprocess_input/8.2.x) then you create a new variable which has your Form ID `$variables['var'] = $form_id;`, and lastly in input.html.twig you would do a simple check, `{% if var == 'specific_form_id' %} ..custom stuff goes here.. {% endif %}`

Comment: Due to this core issue, [Incorrect order and duplicate theme hook suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2752443) regardless of adding a theme suggestion input--textfield.html.twig will still have a higher specificity. Comment [#37](https://www.drupal.org/node/2752443#comment-12036332) links off to a potential solution for the core issue, [Convert theme hooks (defined by hook_theme()) to be objects](https://www.drupal.org/node/2863819).