# How can we add HTML (Font Awesome Icon) to a form's submit button?

Tags: forms

We have used hook alter to customize a form's submit button but any HTML added is ignored. How can we add HTML to a form's submit button so that we can insert a font awesome icon?

For example, in the below code the  tag is ignored.

```
 $form['actions']['submit']["#value"] = "<i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Start Customizing";
```

Comment: May want to see something like this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226491/change-a-normal-submit-input-type-to-button-type-with-button-tag